# Can an App Extension be conditionally included in a build?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane, ios-app-extension, conditional-compilation

I'm starting work on 2 app extensions, and I'd like to set up my builds as follows:

- Builds intended for the App Store should not include either extension
- Builds intended for TestFlight should include the extension that is almost ready
- Local builds should include both extensions

Currently, I have a different build configuration for each of these to show and hide other aspects of the app (and compiler flags in some cases too). I use fastlane to make my builds.

As far as I can tell, the only ways to add or remove an app extension would be:

- Duplicate the main target twice and use one for each of the above builds (drawback - must maintain 3 copies of the target until the extensions are fully complete)
- Manually add/remove the extension before building (drawback - impossible to make both TestFlight and App Store builds from a given branch in a CI environment because manual intervention is required)

Can anyone think of a better solution for conditionally including the app extensions?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a Run Script Build Phase to your main target.

Add this script and replace the configuration names with your own build config names and the extensions with whichever ones you want to include for each configuration:

```
function embedExtensions() {
    for extension in $1
    do
        rsync -r --copy-links "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${extension}.appex" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH}"
    done
}

debug_extensions=("PacketTunnelProvider WidgetExtension ShareExtension")
beta_extensions=("PacketTunnelProvider WidgetExtension")

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]
then
    embedExtensions $debug_extensions
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Beta" ]
then
    embedExtensions $beta_extensions
fi
```

I figured this out by looking at the build output of Xcode’s Embed App Extensions Build Phase which uses an Xcode-internal tool `builtin-copy`. But `rsync` achieves the same result and has broadly the same options. The `--copy-links` option is needed to resolve symlinked `.appex` bundles.